# while compressing the image using bitmap (image)saving to the gallery but image failed to load -Android

Tags: android, android-camera

[image]I am using bitmap.But after capturing image  I am trying to save image in External storage it is getting blured.Please give me solution.
This is my code -

```
public void saveImageToExternalStorage() {
    String root =Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
    File file1 = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file1.exists())
        file1.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file1);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
    // immediately available to the user.
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { file1.toString() },                null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `blured`?

Comment: While compressing image it's saving to gallery but not able to load.@ greenapps

Comment: To galery? `I am trying to save image in External storage` ??? And in your post i read nothing about not beeing able to load. Cant you write a better post? And what is blured?

Comment: I corrected my post.@greenapps

Comment: What error is logcat showing?

Comment: It is not showing error in logcat.When we open image from gallery its failed to load.@Chintan Desai

Comment: @Dhanshri elaborate "failed to load" where are you loading that image

Comment: @Dhanshri i think most of us are like "kehna kia chahti ho :P"

Comment: Image saving in the gallery but image not loading in the gallery I added scrrenshot.@Adeel Turk

Comment: @Dhanshri ok i can seems like your bitmap is invliad there is no other issue .. where and how this  finalBitmap is intialised?

Comment: I declared it as global variable only not initialized@Adeel Turk

Comment: @Dhanshri then your code is running as expetcted .. coz you dont have any thing in your bitmap so what do expect the streams to write in the file ?

Comment: @Dhanshri plus it is impossible that you havent initialsed your variable and you are calling its methods.. it should give you a NULL POINTER EXPECTION in that case (if you havent initialsed finalBitmap object)

Comment: But it didnt give me exception@Adeel Turk

Comment: then its is initialsed somewhere you need to skim through your code again.. it is  impossible to call a method from an un-initialsed object of any class

Comment: Thank u for your time.problem is solved@ Adeel Turk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to notify the gallery that a new image with a path is added or i should say that you must update the MediaStore so that it will be added in Media Store as new Image

```
private void addImageGallery( File file ) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg"); // setar isso
    getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

Comment: doing this you weill see the image in gallery  or photos app as well

Comment: @AdeelTurk is right. Your loading problems with storing could be connected with metadata of your file. I think this is useful answer

Answer (score 0):

It's probably compression fault. Try to modify the parameters of

```
finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
```

to eg:

```
finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
```

or save it to lossless PNG format if it's not against your requirements:

```
finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

Source:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)

Comment: image saving in the gallery but it is not loading.It is giving "LOAD FAILED". @muminers

Comment: Well this is correct answer: blurred picture = hardcore compression. You probably mixed up some parameters